# Using fork and waitpid functions in C to count characters, words, and lines from file with multiple processes

Tags: c

I am trying to use multiple processes with the fork and waitpid functions to modify a program that reads through a file and return the total number of lines, words, and characters. The program compiles and runs fine, but the output always displays zero for all three values even though the file is not empty. Does anyone know how I can fix this? The user enters the file name and the number of child processes they want when they run the program. Here is my code:

```
//wc.h
#ifndef WC_H
#define WC_H

#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct count_t {
        int linecount;
        int wordcount;
        int charcount;
} count_t;

count_t word_count(FILE* fp, long offset, long size);
extern int crashRate;

#endif



//wc_mul.c
#include "wc.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define MAX_PROC 100
#define MAX_FORK 100

int crashRate = 0;

count_t word_count(FILE* fp, long offset, long size)
{
        char ch;
        long rbytes = 0;

        count_t count;
        // Initialize counter variables
        count.linecount = 0;
        count.wordcount = 0;
        count.charcount = 0;
        
        printf("[pid %d] reading %ld bytes from offset %ld\n", getpid(), size, offset);

        if(fseek(fp, offset, SEEK_SET) < 0) {
                printf("[pid %d] fseek error!\n", getpid());
        }

        while ((ch=getc(fp)) != EOF && rbytes < size) {
                // Increment character count if NOT new line or space
                if (ch != ' ' && ch != '\n') { ++count.charcount; }

                // Increment word count if new line or space character
                if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\n') { ++count.wordcount; }

                // Increment line count if new line character
                if (ch == '\n') { ++count.linecount; }
                rbytes++;
        }

        srand(getpid());
        if(crashRate > 0 && (rand()%100 < crashRate)) 
        {
                printf("[pid %d] crashed.\n", getpid());
                abort();
        }

        return count;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
                long fsize;
                FILE *fp;
                int numJobs;
        //plist_t plist[MAX_PROC];
                count_t total, count, buf;
                int i, j, pid, status, p[2];
                int nFork = 0;

        if(argc < 3) {
                printf("usage: wc <# of processes> <filname>\n");
                return 0;
        }
        
        if(argc > 3) {
                crashRate = atoi(argv[3]);
                if(crashRate < 0) crashRate = 0;
                if(crashRate > 50) crashRate = 50;
        }
        printf("crashRate RATE: %d\n", crashRate);


        numJobs = atoi(argv[1]);
        if(numJobs > MAX_PROC) numJobs = MAX_PROC;

        total.linecount = 0;
        total.wordcount = 0;
        total.charcount = 0;

        // Open file in read-only mode
        fp = fopen(argv[2], "r");

        if(fp == NULL) {
                printf("File open error: %s\n", argv[2]);
                printf("usage: wc <# of processes> <filname>\n");
                return 0;
        }

        fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
        fsize = ftell(fp);
        
        fclose(fp);
        // calculate file offset and size to read for each child
        
        for(i = 0; i < numJobs; i++) {
                if(nFork++ > MAX_FORK) return 0;
                pid = fork();
                printf("%d\n", pid);
                if(pid < 0) {
                        printf("Fork failed.\n");
                } else if(pid == 0) {
                        // Child
                        fp = fopen(argv[2], "r");
                        if (pipe(p) != 0)
                          exit(1);                      
                        count = word_count(fp, 0, fsize);
                        write(p[1], count, MAX_PROC);
                        close(p[0]);
                        // send the result to the parent through the message queue
                        fclose(fp);
                        return 0;
                }
        }
        waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
        close(p[1]);
        for (j=0; j < numJobs; j++) {
          read(p[0], buf, MAX_PROC);
          total.linecount += buf.linecount;
          total.wordcount += buf.wordcount;
          total.charcount += buf.charcount;
        }
        // Parent
        // wait for all children
        // check their exit status
        // read the result from normalliy terminated child
        // re-crete new child if there is one or more failed child
        
        printf("\n========== Final Results ================\n");
        printf("Total Lines : %d \n", total.linecount);
        printf("Total Words : %d \n", total.wordcount);
        printf("Total Characters : %d \n", total.charcount);
        printf("=========================================\n");
        return(0);
}
```

Comment: What is `count_t`? Notice that `getc` wants an `int` not a `char` (in order to handle `EOF`)

Comment: You can optimise this program by using `getc()` instead of `fgetc()` . And: where is this message queue?

Comment: @DavidRanieri just updated code, count_t is a struct from another file

Comment: Error messages belong on stderr, and should provide the reason for the failure.  Error messages should not be followed by a usage statement, especially if the error is not related in any way the manner in which the program was called.  The program should fail (usually) when an error occurs.  IOW, `if( fp == NULL ) { perror(argv[2]); return EXIT_FAILURE;}`

Comment: @DavidRanieri : Okay. I rest my case.

Comment: I'd expect theads/processes would not work at all. Once your I/O bus is saturated, the CPU usage will be well below 100%. (possibly 20% or so)

Comment: Note that `fork()` and threads are at best tricky to integrate — you should use either `fork()` or threads but not both.  Since `fork()` creates processes, you are multi-processing, not multi-threading.  You also aren't including any of the relevant threading headers — but you don't show `#include <unistd.h>` which declares `fork()`.  You aren't compiling with stringent enough compiler warning/error options.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler My bad, I completely screwed up with the wording of the problem. I am supposed to use multiple processes for this task, not threads. I updated the post to reflect this. How can I use fork to make this program run correctly with multiple processes?

Comment: You're using the processes correctly, except you've not set up an IPC (Inter-Process Communication) channel.  A pipe might be simplest; one is sufficient, and each child can do its work and write its result to the pipe.  The parent reads values off the pipe and creates the grand total.  It isn't clear how you avoid all the processes doing the same job — you should probably be passing a non-zero offset to some children, and a smaller size than the whole file size.  You should wait for all the children to die; that means a loop around `waitpid()` is appropriate.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler How can I set up a pipe between the parent and child processes in this situation? I'm sorry if that is a stupid question.

Comment: `int fd[2]; if (pipe(fd) != 0) { …report error, etc… }`.  After forking all the children, the parent should `close(fd[1])` — the write end of the pipe.  Each child should `close(fd[0])` — the read end of the pipe.  The children should each use a single `write()` call to write their counts to `fd[1]` and then exit (thereby closing their read end of the pipe).  The parent should read the counts from `fd[0]` in a loop, stopping on EOF (`read()` returning 0 or a negative value).  It can add the counts from the child to its sums as it reads each value. _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_.  As long as you use single writes and reads, there'll be no interference between the data from the separate processes.  You can write the `count_t` structures to the pipe and read them off the pipe.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I edited my code to attempt to do this but now for the line count it always returns 125 multiplied by the number of requested processes (ex: 125 for one process, 250 for two processes, 375 for three processes, etc.) and still returns 0 for the other two values.

Answer (score 4):

No code modifies `total.linecount` in the process that prints it and this variable was not placed in shared memory. So the output will always be zero.

You either need to place the variable in shared memory or you need to modify it in the same process in which you print it. The `fork` function creates a new process that inherits its parent's current view of memory but does not share modifications to memory unless memory is explicitly made shareable.

Were this not so, your code would explode as all the different `fork` children try to modify the *same* `fp` variable!

Where is the code that sums the results from the various children?

Comment: Sorry that was an older version of my code. I updated it to the most up to date version. This version still returns zero for each of the three outputs.

Comment: Same problem. Just as each `fork`ed child modifies its own `fp`, each modifies its own `total.linecount`. There is no code to sum up the results from all the children and give that result to the parent.

Comment: And, by the way, if they were shared, your code would fail for multiple reasons. The shared `fp` would just be one problem. Another would be two processes doing `total.linecount += count.linecount;` at the same time, each reading the same value, then each adding a different value to it, then each writing the sum resulting in one of the additions being lost.

Comment: How can I modify this code so that I won't have to worry about these issues? I'm sorry if that's a stupid question I'm just really struggling with this.

Comment: @GregGruschow It depends on your requirements. You can just use a single process. You can use threads. You can use processes with some form of shared memory. You can use processes with a message queue. Pipes are probably easiest. If you have no experience with any of these techniques, then pick one and learn it -- not so you can do this one task but so that you will have that technique available to you. Coordinating multiple agents is not a simple thing to do and if you've never done it before, you will need a lot of effort to learn how to do it properly.